# How to kill a thread after N seconds?

Tags: python

I want to create threads that will add something to an array, but, if they don't do that in less than 2 seconds, I want to terminate them.

This is a prof of concept, so the code is simple. Every second I want a thread to add that item in the list, so a thread runs after 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 seconds. The idea is to not let the thread 3 and 4 run.

```
import threading, time

myList = []

def foo(value):
    global myList
    time.sleep(value)
    print("Value: {}".format(value))
    myList.append(value)

threads = []

for i in range(5):
    th = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(i,))
    threads.append(th)

for th in threads:
    th.start()
```

What do I do now? I tried using some other logic like using

```
th.join(timeout)
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: First: use a `collections.deque` or a `queue.Queue` to add items to, they are thread-safe (while lists are not). But to the actual problem, what if you just pass the start time to `foo`, and then simply check the time delta to the start time before you add them to the queue? e.g. inside `foo` just check `if time.now() - start_time < 2: q.append(value)`

Comment: You can't "kill" a thread. You must communicate or send a signal somehow to it that it's time to `return` (or they can do it based on some internal reason, like a certain amount of time passing).

Comment: Is the problem that you cannot terminate a thread, or that you can't measure the time it takes to execute the function that you want to take less than 2s to run? For the first you can do something like @martineau said, such as causing an exception or making the function return something. For the other, you could use `asyncio` in each thread, having it run two functions asyncronously, the main function that you want to executre, and the other to check the time passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in a comment you can't really "kill" a thread (externally). However they *can* "commit suicide" by returning or raising a exception.

Below is example of doing the latter when the thread's execution time has exceeded a given amount of time. Note that this is not the same as doing a `join(timeout)` call, which only blocks until the thread ends or the specified amount of time has elapsed. That's why the printing of `value` and its appending to the list happens regardless of whether the thread finishes before the call to `join()` times-out or not.

I got the basic idea of using `sys.settrace()` from the tutorial titled [Different ways to kill a Thread](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/) — although my implementation is slightly different. Also note that this approach likely introduces a significant amount of overhead.

```
import sys
import threading
import time


class TimelimitedThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, time_limit, **kwargs):
        self.time_limit = time_limit
        self._run_backup = self.run  # Save superclass run() method.
        self.run = self._run  # Change it to custom version.
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _run(self):
        self.start_time = time.time()
        sys.settrace(self.globaltrace)
        self._run_backup()  # Call superclass run().
        self.run = self._run_backup  # Restore original.

    def globaltrace(self, frame, event, arg):
        return self.localtrace if event == 'call' else None

    def localtrace(self, frame, event, arg):
        if(event == 'line' and
           time.time()-self.start_time > self.time_limit):  # Over time?
            raise SystemExit()  # Terminate thread.
        return self.localtrace


THREAD_TIME_LIMIT = 2.1  # Secs
threads = []
my_list = []

def foo(value):
    global my_list
    time.sleep(value)
    print("Value: {}".format(value))
    my_list.append(value)

for i in range(5):
    th = TimelimitedThread(target=foo, args=(i,), time_limit=THREAD_TIME_LIMIT)
    threads.append(th)

for th in threads:
    th.start()

for th in threads:
    th.join()

print('\nResults:')
print('my_list:', my_list)
```

Output:

```
Value: 0
Value: 1
Value: 2

Results:
my_list: [0, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score -2):

Join() is used to wait for the respective thread to finish. To terminate a thread, use stop().. You can try as follows:
time.sleep(N)
th.join()

Comment: Threads don't have s `stop()` method.